# Confluence embedded draw.io png created via confluence plugin does not contain xml metadata

Tags: confluence, draw.io

When exporting my diagram created via local draw.io into a png named "sample.png"I can import it back into a blank draw.io project and the objects are parsed out allowing me to proceed with editing the diagram via draw.io

[image]

When I create a new diagram via the draw.io plugin on confluence I am unable to replicate this behaviour - instead my diagram is displayed as an image within the local draw.io diagram

[image]

My hope was to programmatically manipulate the xml that is probably "hidden" somewhere in  sample.png ([How to programatically extract XML data from draw.io PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284570/how-to-programatically-extract-xml-data-from-draw-io-png)) I am searching for a way to force confluence to use the "draw.io formatted png" instead of what I assume to be a default format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported in Confluence. You would have to specifically export PNG+XML.